# Why does the capacitor work like that?

Tags: capacitor

Why does the capacitor work like that?

[image]

In the left circuit the capacitor is discharging because there is a potential difference which was 5 V on one side and 4 V on the other.

Why doesn't it work the same in the second circuit? There is 5 V on one side and 2.5V on the other side

[image]

Comment: The voltage across the capacitor just isn't the same. Remember: voltage is ALWAYS measured between TWO points. In diagrams where they just list the voltage at one point, it is being referenced to some other node in the circuit which has been defined to be 0V (the reference node, aka labelled as ground)

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: @winny Yes. DKNguyen So why does it work like that ? Even thought there is a potential difference.

Comment: The voltage across the capacitor is simply not the full voltage from the source. That's all there is to it. Do you now what a resistor divider is? Don't even worry about the capacitor. Just look up how a resistor divider works. Sounds like you skipped too many steps. Not much different from how something dropped from the 10th floor will have less energy if falls on your head when you are standing on the 5th floor rather than the 1st floor.

Comment: @user331990 Judging from your comments to other answers, I think you don't have the fundamentals right now to properly understand what is going on. Forget capacitors and just look at combination of only resistors for now. Then combinations of only capacitors.

Comment: I know how the voltage divider works. And I know that each resistor has 2,5V. Also the current flows from 5V to 2,5V and from 2,5V to 0V. Just like the basics how te current flows. As I know the current always flows from High potential to Low potential so that's why I was curious why the voltage from capacitor which was 5V didn't flow to 2,5V where in the left one it did from 5V to 4V.

Comment: For your purposes, current flows *in loops*, not straight lines, which will throw a wrench into things if you merely think of current as flowing from a higher to lower potential. It's better to think in terms of sources and loads. Both have voltages but the voltage across a source is an action where the voltage across a load is a reaction. Like Newton, where you can produce a force to push something but when you push something it applies a reaction force against you which is equal and opposite.

Comment: The sources in a circuit produce a voltage across their terminals of their own accord. The loads in a circuit do not produce a voltage. Any voltage drop that appears across a load is in reaction to currents being pushed through them by the source. Like Newton, these collective reaction voltages must overall be equal and opposite to the source voltages. And currents flow in loops, so re-examine your understanding of the circuit with this perspective instead of your "higher potential to lower potential" concept.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of information. It's just that my knowlage of how current was flowing destroyed. So I have some problems trying to accept that current from capacitor doesn't flow from high potential to lower potential. But I undestand that it is like that. But it's hard understand it now because I belived for so long that it work that way :D

Comment: @user331990 Try looking at it from the perspective of "action" voltages and "reaction" voltages. That should help clear things up, hopefully. Something like a resistor can only ever be a load and so can only have a "reaction" voltage.  But a capacitor can act as a load when it charges up pr act as a source when it supplies charge so it can have an "action" or "reaction" voltage depending on what is going on in the rest circuit. That's basically the difference between your left and right diagram.

Comment: Imagine if you pulled a giant heavy wheel behind you. You are the voltage source and the wheel is the capacitor. As long as you pull more hard and fast enough you stored energy in the wheel just like charging up a capacitor. But if you slow down (i.e. turn the voltage source down), now suddenly the wheel is no longer storing energy but supplying energy. It will continue to roll and run you over. This is like turning down the power supply voltage after the cap has charged up and the cap voltage now exceeds the power supply's voltage. It will back charge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The capacitor is a voltage source, somewhat like a cell (or battery of cells),  except that unlike a cell, the potential difference across it changes with time, as current flows through it.

This means that at any instant in time, you could redraw your circuit replacing the capacitor with a cell of the same potential difference that the capacitor had at that instant. The currents in the circuit at that instant in time can be calculated as if the capacitor were a cell, and will therefore depend on the charge state (the voltage across the capacitor) at that instant.

Redrawing your right-hand circuit (the potential divider) three times, each time with the capacitor in a different charge state, we might get this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8M5iL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In each case, the potentials marked in red are the consequence of the two voltage sources, B1 and C, imposing their respective potential differences across various elements.

#### Resistor currents

In circuit A (left) the capacitor is completely discharged, and has no potential difference across it. For analysis we may consider it (for an instant in time) to be a zero volt source. Therefore the voltage across R1 is zero, and the current through it must also be zero. R2 must therefore have all the remaining 5V of B1's EMF across it, by Kirchhoff's voltage law (KVL), for a current of 5mA.

In circuit B (middle), the capacitor is initially charged to 5V, and those 5V are placed directly across R1, causing a current of 5mA through R1. By KVL again, R2 doesn't have any potential difference across it, so it's passing no current.

In circuit C (right), the capacitor is initially charged to 2.5V, which is imposed directly across R1, and so R1 passes 2.5mA. The remaining 2.5V of B1's EMF is across R2, also causing 2.5mA of current through R2.

#### Capacitor current

With all resistor currents known, we can work out what currents would flow through C, in order to obey Kirchhoff's current law (KCL). In circuit A, clearly all 5mA through R2 must be coming via C, since there's no current via R1.

In circuit B, for KCL to be obeyed, a current of 5mA must be flowing upwards through C, because none of the current flowing down through R1 is leaving via R2.

In circuit C, it's fairly obvious that no current can be flowing through C, since all of the 2.5mA flowing down through R1 is also leaving via R2.

#### Charging or discharging?

We can use current direction through C to determine if C is charging or discharging. In circuit A current flows downwards through C, so C is charging. That makes sense, because it has no initial charge.

For circuit B, the direction of current through C is in a direction that would act to ***discharge*** C. That is, the if C were a capacitor, then its potential difference would be ***reducing*** from 5V.

In circuit C, there's no current through C, so C is neither charging or discharging.

#### Conclusions

Circuit C demonstrates what would happen when the voltage across a capacitor equals the voltage that *would* be between those same two nodes if the capacitor weren't there at all. If you removed component C, there would be 2.5V across R1. If you then place a 2.5V source (a charged capacitor, a battery, a photovoltaic cell, literally *any* voltage source of 2.5V) across R1, ***nothing changes***!

When C is a capacitor, if it has no initial charge, clearly it will begin to charge and that charging will continue until the potential difference across it equals the potential difference that would be across R1 if C weren't there, which is 2.5V

If C has an initial charge of 5V, it will begin to discharge, and will continue to do so until the potential difference across it equals the potential difference that would be across R1 if C weren't there, which is 2.5V.

In fact, regardless of the current state of charge of C, it will always charge or discharge until the voltage across it becomes equal to the voltage that ***would*** be present if C weren't there at all.

When capacitor C's charge arrives at 2.5V, charging/discharging halts, because in that condition, no current flows via C any more.

#### Thevenin equivalent

This behaviour might be easier to understand when B1, R1 and R2 are replaced by their [Thevenin equivalent](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenins-theorem/) circuit. That would look like this, in the blue box, right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgfSMJ.png)</sup>

I'll leave it up to you to study Thevenin equivalency, but it's clearer in the right-hand circuit that the capacitor will eventually settle at a charge of 2.5V, regardless of its initial state. Also, by reducing the network of R1 and R2 to a single resistance Rt (500Ω in this case), the time constant of the capacitor's charge/discharge curve becomes obvious.

Comment: Your schematics may be confusing by using a battery symbol for a capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

A capacitor's charging current is proportional to the rate of change of voltage across it, not the actual voltage. In the right-hand diagram, the current through the two resistors is equal as are the voltages across them. So there is no reason why any current should flow through the capacitor. The circuit is stable with no changing voltages. dv/dt=0 and so Icharge also equals 0.

Comment: But on the left one it is discharging because of voltage differential. So on the right one it doesn't work ?

Comment: On the left one there is a voltage across the resistor forcing a charging current. On the right one, all of the current in the top resistor flows through the bottom resistor because they have equal voltages across them, When the current in the two resistors is equal there can be no current through the capacitor by Kirchoff's current law.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't it work the same in the second circuit? There is 5 V on
> one side and 2.5V on the other side

Do you understand the concept of *steady state*?
The second circuit appears to be in steady state - if you measure voltages and/or currents at one moment, they will be the same at another moment. For this to be true, the capacitor must remain charged at 2.5V.

One might ask, "Well, how did the capacitor get charged?".
At some point during the circuit's construction, current flows...the capacitor attains its voltage. In the second circuit, current continues to flow through the two resistors, but it is constant - the circuit has reached its steady state.
At first construction, current flow from the 5V source is higher than steady state current - this extra current charges up the capacitor.

Comment: Can we move it into chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138499/discussion-between-user331990-and-dknguyen).

Comment: @DKNguyen in chat it will be easier for me to follow what are you trying to tell me.

Comment: @All - After so many comments, chat is now the only option on this answer, as comments on Stack Exchange should not be used for extended discussion. Since the system has created a chatroom for this answer already (link above) we will leave that in place, rather than the usual process of creating a new chatroom. The comments which were here (and which are now in the chatroom) have been deleted from here. **Keep it in chat now, please**. Any further comments posted here may deleted without notice. Thanks.